# Show custom attribute of selected child item instead of their parent in product details page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-attributes, simple-product

How can i Show custom attribute of selected child item instead of   parent/ConfigurableProduct attribute value in product details page in Magento 2

Parent/Configurable product:

[image]

Here Child Product admin & Front:

[image]
[image]